# MVC.NET, JQuery - How to submit a form that is made up of a JQuery datatable with rows that contain checkboxes and text inputs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a jquery datatable that has multiple rows that contain checkboxes and text input fields. My object is to select all the rows that have the checkboxes checked and submit them via ajax. I am able to get the "id" attribute of all the checkboxes that are checked, but how do I get the values (labels and text inputs) of the columns in the rest of the row?

I also need to post these to an action via an ajax call. How should I go about doing and how do I catch these values in the post action?

I have a Student model.

```
public class Student {

public string studentid { get; set; }
public string firstname { get; set; }
public string lastname { get; set; }

}
```

The view is bound to this model (`@model Project.Models.IEnumerable<Student>`) and the datatable is generated with the following:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Select</td>
<td>StudentId</td>
<td>FirstName</td>
<td>LastName</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    foreach (var student in Model)
    {
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="@student.studentid"/></td>
    <td>@student.studentid</td>
    <td>@student.firstname</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="@student.lastname"/></td>
    }
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

The last name field is editable, and only the rows that have the checkbox checked should be updated in the database.

So when i submit this form, in the post action, would I do this?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateStudent(IEnumerable<Student> students)
{

}
```

I have tried the above method, but have not had any success. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop because it generates duplicate `name` attributes without indexers therefore they can't be bound to a collection (it also generates invalid html because of the dulicate `id` attributes). You must use either a `for` loop and make you model `IList<T>` or a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Student`.

Comment: You should also use the strongly typed helpers to bind to your properties e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].LastName)` and use a view model that includes a `bool IsSelected` property so that you can use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a `foreach` loop because it generates duplicate `name` attributes without indexers and therefore they can't be bound to a collection (it also generates invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes). You must use either a `for` loop and make you model `IList<Student>` or a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Student`.

Since unchecked checkboxes do not post a value, but textboxes will, you need to start by creating a view model with a (say) `bool IsSelected` property that you can bind to using `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` and ensure that a value will always be posted that matches up with the corresponding textbox.

```
public class StudentVM
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view

```
@model List<yourAssembly.StudentVM>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        ....
        <tbody>
            for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ID)
                    </td>
                    ....
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].LastName)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" ... />
}
```

And your controller methods might look like

```
public ActionResult UpdateStudent()
{
    List<StudentVM> model = db.Students.Select(s => new StudentVM
    {
        ID = s.studentid,
        FirstName = s.firstname,
        LastName = s.lastname
    });
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateStudent(List<StudentVM> model)
{
    var selectedStudents = model.Where(s => s.IsSelected);
    // save and redirect
}
```

Comment: How would you add validation to this form to make sure that if a checkbox is checked, then the corresponding last name input field MUST contain a value? I tried using Data Annotations with little success. I also want to prevent form submission of none of the checkboxes are checked..

Comment: For the first one, you can use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) or similar `[RequiredIfTrue]` attribute. For example `[RequiredIfTrue("IsSelected", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a last name")]public string LastName { get; set; }`

Comment: Unfortunately the second can't be done with the built-in client side validation. You need to write your own scripts or handle it on the server and add a `ModelState` error the return the view